# Why is this javascript function not able to call this other function?

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick

I have a simple function that uses javascript to write a table to the body of a webpage. If I call the function directly when the submit button is pressed, it calls the function and it executes properly, but if I wrap the function in another function, such as function constructor()..., it doesn't do anything. I'm very new to javascript and am really just looking for an explanation of why this works the way that it does.

```
function makeTable(){
var body = document.body,
    tbl = document.createElement('table');
tbl.style.width  = '100px';
tbl.style.border = '1px solid black';
for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    var row = tbl.insertRow();
    for(var j = 0; j < 2; j++){
            var cell = row.insertCell();
            cell.style.border = '1px solid black';
            var myText = document.createTextNode("some val");
            cell.appendChild(myText);
        }
    }
    body.appendChild(tbl);
}

function constructor(){
maketable();
}
```

The HTML

```
<!--
test.html
-->

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
    <title>JS Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="generator" content="Geany 1.27" />
</head>

<body>
    <script src = "test.js"></script>
    <form>  
    </form>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="makeTable()"/>

    <div id="output"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Dont know if it is just here or in your actual code but `makeTable()` in your function is wrongfully spelled.

Comment: Yes, I realized that after I posted this question and changed it. It still, however, doesn't execute the function.

Comment: Maybe try using a different function name. Additionally you obviously have to call that function too.

Answer (score 1):

look at how u spelled the function!!

```
function constructor(){
    maketable();
}
```

It should be `makeTable();`
:D

Comment: Yeah, I realized that after I submitted it. It still, however, doesn't execute.